# Confusion in String concept

Tags: java

```
class StringTest1
{
public static final void main(String... a)
{
    String str1="JAVA";
    String str2="WORLD";

    String str3=str1+str2;
}
}
```

How many objects will be created in this process?
I think 3 objects will be created.

```
class StringTest2
{
public static final void main(String... a)
{

    String strTest="JAVA"+"WORLD";
}
}
```

How many objects will be created in this process?How many objects are accessible?
somebody told me that "JAVA"+"WORLD" is an expression and it would not stored in string pool.

Comment: in the first example you are asking for 3 variables to store a reference to 3 string objects, one of which is the result of concatenation. in the second example then my guess is the compiler will optimize to create only one string object.

Comment: String strTest="JAVA"+"WORLD"; statement is using in different program.

Answer (score 5):

In the first example, you will end up with three `String` objects. You can actually see this in the bytecode.

Assume you have the following code:

```
public class StrTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "JAVA";
        String str2 = "WORLD";

        String str3 = str1 + str2;

        String strTest = "JAVA" + "WORLD";
    }
}
```

The resulting bytecode is:

```
public class StrTest {
  public StrTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String JAVA
       2: astore_1      
       3: ldc           #3                  // String WORLD
       5: astore_2      
       6: new           #4                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       9: dup           
      10: invokespecial #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      13: aload_1       
      14: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      17: aload_2       
      18: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      21: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      24: astore_3      
      25: ldc           #8                  // String JAVAWORLD
      27: astore        4
      29: return        
}
```

You can see that the Java compiler has created two `String` instances for `"JAVA"` and `"WORLD"` in the string pool. To append these two together, it created a `StringBuilder` instance and appended the values. After that, it calls `toString()` on that instance, which creates a new `String` instance with `"JAVAWORLD"` inside it.

In the second case, you only end up with one `String` instance because the Java compiler is smart enough to see that what you basically have is a constant, and so it performs some compile-time optimization by evaluating that expression and creating **one** `String` instance in the string pool that contains `"JAVAWORLD"`. The reference to that instance is then assigned to `strTest`.

With regard to the strings `"JAVA"`, `"WORLD"`, and `"JAVAWORLD"`, these are basically interned strings. Since strings are immutable in Java, you only need one reference to a unique instance which can be reused in multiple locations in the code. This is basically a way to save memory.

So to sum up:

- Case 1: Three `String` instances: two in the pool, one newly-constructed after appending (a `StringBuilder` instance was also created to append the two strings, leading to 4 objects total).
- Case 2: One instance in the pool.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str1="JAVA";
String str2="WORLD";

String strTest="JAVA"+"WORLD";
```

Each of the three lines will result in the creation of one String object. But it will always be the same object if the code is resulted multiple times. Also, each String object will contain a `char[]` object, so technically, it's 2 objects per line.

---

```
String str3=str1+str2;
```

Assuming this cannot be optimized by the `javac`, it will compiled as

```
String str3 = new StringBuilder(str1).append(str2).toString();
```

so, it will not only create a String, but also a StringBuilder which is not accessible in the code. Thus, in worst case 4 objects are created: String, StringBuilder and to char arrays (because it has to be resized during `append`)

Answer (score 0):

In the first case compiler can not be sure what values `str1` and `str2` will have, so it is not a constant expression and thus it will be evaluated in runtime. There will be three objects (two from string literals and one created as its concatenation).

In the second case compiler is able to compute result, so there will be just one object, as if you wrote `"JAVAWORLD"`

Answer (score 0):

In first case three objects will get created and all of them will be accessible since you are having live references to them.

In second case if you are doing something like

```
String str1="JAVA";
String str2="WORLD";
String strTest="JAVA"+"WORLD";
```

Then there will be three objects that will get created. Here "JAVA" will be in String object pool while you are creating strTest so it will not allocate memory for that and it will take direct reference from the pool. Similarly for "WORLD" too. And then a new object will get created out of these two objects and it will be assigned to strTest. The accessible objects here will be 3.

But if you are doing something like

```
 String strTest="JAVA"+"WORLD";
```

Here only ONE object is accessible to you which is "JAVAWORLD". References to "JAVA" and "WORLD" are there in pool but there is no way you can directly access them. As @Vivin Paliath mentioned "JAVA" and "WORLD" will be interned to form a new Object "JAVAWORLD". Hence, only two objects gets created.

For more information related to String object pool [see here](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200409/ScjpTipLine-StringsLiterally.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The second part is wrong. Three objects are not created when you do `String strTest = "JAVA" + "WORLD";`. Only one instance is created (`"JAVAWORLD"`) and that is in the pool. `strTest` is only a reference to that (interned) `String` instance.

Comment: @VivinPaliath : corrected the answer. :) Thanks for pointing the mistake.